# SSL error using curl/wget

Tags: ssl, curl, wget

Recently, I started seeing this problem on my Mac.  I am able to download files or visit any https web page from Chrome, but I am not able to do that anymore with either curl or wget.

```
$ curl --verbose https://www.google.com/
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4007:803::2004...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (::1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /Users/tomkwong/anaconda3/ssl/cacert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443 
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443
```

Here's the wget error:

```
$ wget --verbose https://www.google.com/
--2018-03-27 23:53:32--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4007:803::2004, 172.217.14.68
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|2607:f8b0:4007:803::2004|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

More information by using openssl command as requested.  I'm unsure what to make sense out of it... looks like errno=54 means "Connection reset by peer".

```
$ openssl s_client -debug -connect www.google.com:443 -prexit
CONNECTED(00000003)
write to 0x7feb37558870 [0x7feb3800ca00] (307 bytes => 307 (0x133))
0000 - 16 03 01 01 2e 01 00 01-2a 03 03 73 60 8a 49 d5   ........*..s`.I.
0010 - ad 36 db 41 da 14 20 c9-85 7b f8 5b 2b b3 2b c0   .6.A.. ..{.[+.+.
0020 - b6 47 e1 c5 b9 75 b9 c2-9d d9 1c 00 00 ac c0 30   .G...u.........0
0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-00 07 c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c   .<./...A........
00c0 - c0 02 00 05 00 04 c0 12-c0 08 00 16 00 13 00 10   ................
00d0 - 00 0d c0 0d c0 03 00 0a-00 ff 01 00 00 55 00 0b   .............U..
00e0 - 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a-00 1c 00 1a 00 17 00 19   ................
00f0 - 00 1c 00 1b 00 18 00 1a-00 16 00 0e 00 0d 00 0b   ................
0100 - 00 0c 00 09 00 0a 00 23-00 00 00 0d 00 20 00 1e   .......#..... ..
0110 - 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01-05 02 05 03 04 01 04 02   ................
0120 - 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03-02 01 02 02 02 03 00 0f   ................
0130 - 00 01 01                                          ...
read from 0x7feb37558870 [0x7feb38012000] (7 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1522221838
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 307 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1522221838
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: You can get more detailed data on the handshake using `openssl s_client -debug -connect www.google.com:443 -prexit` - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742003/debugging-ssl-handshake

Comment: Updated with more information.  I'm unsure how to decipher the additional information.  The write:errno=54 seems to mean "connection reset by peer" which doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score -3):

Rebooting the computer fixes the problem!
I should have thought about that earlier :-)