# Curl SMTP working on local machine but not server

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, curl, smtp

So I am running this command on my local machine

```
curl --url 'smtps://mail.name.com:465' --ssl-reqd --mail-from '<myEmail>' --mail-rcpt '<toEmail>' --upload-file mail.txt --user '<myEmail>:<password>' --insecure
```

And then my mail.txt file looks like this

```
To: <toEmail>
From: <fromEmail>
Subject: Test

Test msg
```

Now this works totally normal on my local home computer, but when I use this on an Ubuntu server (19.10) it just hangs and never does send, I made sure that there are no other processes running on the port 465, as well as made sure that none of my other SMTP services were somehow running.

If it matters, I am using Name.com for the SMTP server provider, and using Linode as the hosting service.

Comment: [How to debug SSL handshake using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17742003/608639) A description and *"it just hangs"* is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww Thank you for your response, I believe that the issue is actually spawning from a different problem, if you would like to help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504205/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-ssmtp is the new post I made.