# SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol

Tags: java, ssl, kubernetes, curl

Trying to do a curl from a kubernetes pod by exec-ing into it and I see the below error. Both server and client have the certs imported into their truststore/keystore.

```
bash-4.4$ curl -v --cert tls.crt --key tls.key --cacert ca.crt https://<host>:9090/api/tks
*   Trying ....
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <host> port 9090 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ca.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Server logs for the same request are as below. Not sure if they are related, and also it seems like the protocol is not same for both server and client.

```
SSL handshake failed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate) (UNKNOWN)
```

Comment: `* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):` `* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate`. `curl` might not get correct certificate. There is an option `-servername`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611193/use-self-signed-certificate-with-curl.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll check the certs. Also another question I have is from the curl output it seems like client is communicating via `TLSv1.3` where as the server seems to be communicating via `TLSv1.2`. Could that be a reason for 2nd error I posted?

Comment: 1.3 handshake fails (most probably the error in the log), then 1.2 handshake fails. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67435623/18980756 for more tracing options.