# asp.net web api: IIS8 - (413) Request Entity Too Large

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-413

I have **asp.net web api** application hosted in **IIS**. This app has 100mb in `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength=...` and in `<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength=...`. But sometimes client gets `413 Request entity too large` in resoponse for quite small requests. I saw some fixes like "just change uploadreadaheadsize". But actually for me this solution is not clear. Why do I face this error when request limits are configured properly? 
**Update1:** one more detail - this app uses client certificates authentication.
**Update2**: I found this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737382(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300064/getting-413-errors-on-iis-with-concurrent-sessions-using-the-same-https-client-c) you can find a description of reason for this problem. I set **uploadreadaheadsize** to **1 mb** instead of default **49152 b**. I used this powershell script:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webserver/serverruntime" -name "uploadreadaheadsize" -value 1048576
```

Actually I think this script should work too (it's not so global):

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "iis:\Sites" -location "sitename here" -filter "system.webserver/serverruntime" -name "uploadreadaheadsize" -value 1048576
```