# BizTalk WCF returns 413 when using client certificates authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk

I have found the following behavior of WCF in combination with BizTalk:

I have a BizTalk application, in which I published the orchestration as a WCF Service and I changed the binding to allow a maximum received file size of 2 GB. When I submit a request larger than 65KB it works fine with basic authentication and anonymous. As soon as I enable Client certificate authentication I get 413 Request Entity Too Large. Is this a known issue in BizTalk, or is there something I am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I thought my question was related to BizTalk, but as I soon discovered, it was a general issue with WCF and IIS. I found my answer here:
[Getting 413 errors on IIS with concurrent sessions using the same HTTPS client certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300064/getting-413-errors-on-iis-with-concurrent-sessions-using-the-same-https-client-c)

As it turns out: I needed to add this to my config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <serverRuntime enabled="true" uploadReadAheadSize="20747520" />
</system.webServer>
```

Don't forget to unlock the  tag:
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime