# How to send "Certificate Request" in IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, wireshark, client-certificates

I have a web site configured in IIS to Accept, but not require client certificates. When a request is made to our site, I do not see the "Certificate Request" in our after the "Server Hello" in WireShark.

[image]

I have even changed the IIS settings of the website to require client certs, but I don't see the certificate request in from the server in wireshark.

Comment: Dig the related RFC documents from IETF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same effect after setting up IIS (IIS Express 10.0 in my case) to require client certificates.
The "Certificate Request" message from IIS started to appear in Wireshark only after I've configured client certificate negotiation during initial TLS handshake as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18251035/4965108) answer.

Comment: Hey, are OID Filters extension supported in the CertificateRequest message on IIS/.NET? Can't find any info if it's possible to configure this extension.

Answer (score 1):

> ...  but not require client certificates. ...  I do not see the "Certificate Request" i

A Certificate Request is only send if the server requires a certificate for a client, i.e. when you configure the server to require client certificates. Because why should the server request a client certificate if the server does not need it at all?

Comment: Even when I require ssl and require client certificates, the certificate Request is not sent. The same "Server Key Exchange" exchange is used.

Comment: @Nick: then something is configured wrong. If properly configured that client certificates are required then a CertificateRequest will be send.

Comment: @Nick: Somehow it is not configured that this site is needing a client certificate. I have no idea what you did and thus I cannot tell you what went wrong.