# 403.7 forbidden using client certificate windows 10

Tags: iis, certificate, windows-10, client-certificates

I have an application that we have set up to use client certificate authentication in test and when I access it from my development machine running windows 10 it prompts me to select the certificate.  Then having done so it takes me to a 403 forbidden page which on looking in the iis logs is a 403.7.

My development machine is running windows 10 and I get the same error browsing with firefox or IE.

If I install my client certificate on a different machine it works.

The client certificate has a primary key and all stages are trusted, and the trusted root ca is in my trusted roots.

The SSL handshake is completing successfully its rejecting at the certificate end.

Additionally trying to access the production environment has the same behaviour when done from my windows 10 machine, and works from other machines.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are saying the same client certificate installed on a different computer works fine ? but when using localhost,it does not work fine.Am I correct ?

Comment: The site I am trying to connect to is on a server A.  From my client machine B the certificate doesn't work when I connect to A, from client machine C it does.

Answer (score 0):

As you are experiencing issue with local machine only,this probably is because of clientcertnegotiation setting. Look at second answer of this question - using netsh to enable [clientcertnegotiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518314/make-iis-require-ssl-client-certificate-during-initial-handshake)

Comment: Hi, this isn't with the server running on my local machine it is with a remote server.