# What does client certificate negotiation enabled do?

Tags: wcf

I know this has been answered but I felt it doesnt confirm what I experienced having read [When do I need "Negotiate Client Certificate" to be set to Enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024391/when-do-i-need-negotiate-client-certificate-to-be-set-to-enabled)

Firstly a third party sent us https messages to our Wcf api
which was intermittently accepting messages. We then isolated the issue to messages over a few kb!

Initially we increased max message size from default to 48mb to no avail.

In the end I  fix by setting netsh cert negotiate enabled.

Other stack overflow articles suggests it didnt work out right but my issue the connection was working but isolated to message sizes... can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Based on your problem description, it's hard for me to determine where the problem is. The function of the client certificate should be to make a secure connection to the server. But your question doesn't seem to be like that.